# Как использовать YMKMapObjectVisitor для YMKMapObjectCollection?

Tags: ios, swift, yandexmapkit

Не понимаю, как можно пройти по массиву объектов `mapWindow.map.mapObjects`. По идее `YMKMapObjectVisitor` для этого и нужен. Только как им воспользоваться не очень ясно. Может у кого-нибудь есть пример как например пройтись по всем `YMKPlacemarkMapObject`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо использовать метод traverse класса YMKMapObjectCollection: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/mapkit/3.x/concepts/ios/mapkit/ref/YMKMapObjectCollection-docpage/#method_detail__method_traverseWithMapObjectVisitor__nonnullid_YMKMapObjectVisitor_generic